# Does the installation of a PHP extension require a restart or reload of PHP-FPM?

Tags: php, imagemagick, centos7

In my specific case I work with a CentOS 7 environment with both PHP-FPM 5.4 and 7.1 installed. I recently installed php-pecl-imagick and was wondering if a reload or restart was in order to make use of the service, or not at all. (and if httpd needed to be restarted/reloaded) The PHP manual doesn't seem to give an answer on this, and I've seen different recommendations in installation manuals.

Comment: Yup, you need to restart php and Apache/Nginx or else the changes won't be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You need to restart the apache service after PHP extensions are installed / uninstalled. If you have SSH communication, you can try the command below.

```html
service http restart
// service (service name) restart
```